# how to access ExchangeUser() object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook

Im developing an Outlook Web addin to replace and existing Outlook VSTO addin.

Part of the addin grabs the current users details and does this via the 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchnageUser' class (c#) but i cant find the equivalent in the Office.js library.

Should I be using EWS and making calls to the api to retrieve the details?

Many thanks for any help that can be offered

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue, EWS is what you need. See the [GetPersona operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getpersona-operation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which returns a set of properties that are associated with a persona. Here is what MSDN states:

> The GetPersona operation provides access to aggregated contact information in the form of a persona. The PersonaId element in the request identifies the persona to return in the response. The response can contain a default set of persona properties or a custom property set. We recommend that you specify a custom property set so that unused properties are not processed and sent from the server to the client.

Comment: Thank you, I expected as much, Many thanks for your help

Comment: How do I get the PersonaID that is required to pass into that call?  Ive looked and I cannot see any reference on how to obtain it?